# ARIMA or SARIMA scale and normalize data

Tags: forecasting, arima, normalization, categorical-encoding, feature-scaling

Good evening everyone,
I am here to ask a question regarding the statistical models ARIMA & SARIMA use to build predictive models based on past values and with the intent of predicting future values.
My question is this: should the data that the statistical model takes as input be normalized and scaled as is the case for any dataset that goes as input to a Machine Learning model?
Should categorical variables be transformed via one-hot-encoding?
How should date features be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARIMA/SARIMA does not require any scaling. (Nor is it the case that "any dataset that goes as input to a Machine Learning model" needs to be scaled.)

(S)ARIMA can't deal with any predictors at all, so your question about encoding of categorical predictors is moot. There is (S)ARIMAX, or regression with (S)ARIMA errors. [These are different things.](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) If you fit such a model, categorical predictors will usually be encoded one-hot, but honestly, it does not matter a lot. Your software should do this under the hood.

(S)ARIMA expects data with a predefined seasonal frequency, i.e., number of periods per season. As such, there is no notion of "dates". You might have a vector of observations with a frequency of 7, and that might be daily data with weekly seasonality. Or you might have a frequency of 4, and your data might be quarterly with yearly seasonality - or it might be aggregates per six-hour-buckets with daily seasonality! It doesn't matter, and (S)ARIMA won't care. All it cares about is the frequency.

([Note that (S)ARIMA has major problems with "long" seasonality, e.g., daily data with yearly seasonality.](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) Daily data with weekly seasonality is fine, monthly data with yearly seasonality too.)

Comment: Okay thank you. 
In my case, there are 36 dates (year 2021,2022,2023) and I want to predict the cost of a variable in year 2023.
So train my model on year 2021/2022 and test it on year 2023. 
Notably, there are other predictors that come into play, such as a person's age and gender.
In this case, is the pre-processing on the data that I would perform on a machine learning model the same as I would perform on SARIMA?

Comment: If you have 36 data points in 2021-2023, do you have monthly data? I presume you only have part of the 2023 observations, right? Note that (S)ARIMA is a "local" model that will fit a model to each separate time series, and presumably the gender will not change during the time series, and age will only increase linearly, so if there is an age effect, the (S)ARIMA model should capture it automatically. If you have time-varying predictors, you can feed them into your (S)ARIMA model as-is, and your tool should do any conversions to dummies etc.

Comment: Yes, it is 36 observations as for each year I have 12 observations (average of the costs of the variable to be predicted in that month, for example the cost of monthly subscriptions for each month of that year).
From 2023, in this case, I have all the observations, but the concept could be limited to some of them, since we are still in 2023. I am working in a controlled environment, not on real data for now.

Comment: At this point I would like to ask you if my reasoning is correct: taken such a defined dataset, in addition to categorical variables such as sex and other predictors such as age, can I feed it to the SARIMA model as well as I would do with a normal LSTM?

I try to explain myself better if I have expressed myself incorrectly and apologize in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can just feed it in. (S)ARIMA in principle works only on the time series itself, plus any frequency attribute, per my answer above. Note that you have a very short history - two full cycles (24 months) is the absolute minimum for (S)ARIMA to even start considering seasonality. I would be very careful about feeding in any predictors, you will overfit quickly. [You may find this textbook useful.](https://otexts.com/fpp3/)

Comment: Okay thank you. 
My goal is to figure out the future price of the variable "y" (which can be any) based on the previous data, but I need to do this by considering other predictors as well, with the goal of understanding which variables affect the variable "y" the most.
For this purpose I had thought of using an LSTM or a statistical model such as ARIMA & (S)ARIMA, or any other statistical model.
Clearly, some coding needs to be done on some types of data (categorical dates\variables such as sex)